# Display message box of cell value if a corresponding cell value is equal to criteria

Tags: vba, excel, range, messagebox

I need help trying to program excel VBA. There are two ranges, H3:H100 & A3:A100

I'm trying to do the following:

On **Workbook open**, if a cell in range H3:H100 = "PERMIT EXPIRES WITHIN 7 DAYS", then display a message box showing the corresponding "A" column cell value saying: "Permit (Column A cell value) Expires in 7 days"

This is the code that I have:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
For Each cell In Range("I3:I100")
If cell.Value = "Y" And cell.Value <> "" Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
cell.Font.ColorIndex = 10
cell.Font.Bold = True
ElseIf cell.Value = "N" And cell.Value <> "" Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
cell.Font.Bold = True
End If

Next
For Each cell In Range("H3:H100")
If cell.Value = "PERMIT EXPIRES WITHIN 7 DAYS" And cell.Value <> "" Then
MsgBox "Permit (" & cell.Row & ":" & cell.Column & ") Expires in Seven Days", vbExclamation, "Alert"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

It does work, however it displays the intersecting row and column number, not the actual cell value in the "A" range.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Cells` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820928.aspx) to get the *value* of the cell in column A given the row index:

```
Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
```

Indices are 1-based, so the *1* here means column A.